# Replication Factor in SNAPSHOTS (in HDFS)

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, snapshot, cloudera-manager

Can we change the replication factor in HDFS. Say if we enable a snapshot on a hdfs dir then in that case it will replicate the same way replication factor is set on that directory.

Replication Factor on hdfs dir - 3

Then for snapshots it would be - 
for requested snapshot dir : orignal dir *3 times + snapshot *3times

Is there a way by which we can alter the replication factor for snapshot directory in hdfs without altering anything with hdfs dir?

I'm taking snapshots on a given dir using Cloudera Manager

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know at the moment HDFS snapshots are read-only, so you can't change their replication factor.

Apart from that, Snapshot do not copy/replicate data. They are just poiners to original data. So, if you have a x3 replication setup on a snapshottable dir, it will remain x3 no matter how many snapshots you take of it.

Comment: Thanks man. Really appreciate a response. I too thought it can't be changed explicitly for snapshot dir unless we alter something with hdfs dir. Though a requirement came along to look after it, if its possible at all.